# Calculate days based on date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have data like below

```
create table #Temp(Id int, FromDate date, ToDate date)
Insert into #Temp
values(1,'9/1/2019','9/1/2019'),
        (2,'9/2/2019','9/3/2019'),
        (3,'9/2/2019','9/3/2019'),
        (4,'9/4/2019','9/6/2019'),
        (5,'9/7/2019','9/7/2019')
```

I am trying to calculate the difference and create days i.e Day 1, Day 2-3 etc...

Expected result

```
Id  FromDate    ToDate      Display
1   01/09/2019  01/09/2019  Day 1
2   02/09/2019  03/09/2019  Day 2-3
3   02/09/2019  03/09/2019  Day 2-3
4   04/09/2019  06/09/2019  Day 4-6
5   07/09/2019  07/09/2019  Day 7
```

I have tried below code using datediff, but not sure how to relate to previous row and get the date range

```
select *, DATEDIFF(DAY,FromDate,ToDate)
from #Temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use first_value

```
select *
 , datediff(day, first_value(FromDate) over(order by FromDate), FromDate) + 1
 , datediff(day, first_value(FromDate) over(order by FromDate), ToDate) + 1
from #Temp
```

Comment: Hey @Serg. To get the Output they want. `select *
 , 'Day ' + cast(datediff(day, first_value(FromDate) over(order by FromDate), FromDate) + 1 as varchar(10))
 + '-' + cast(datediff(day, first_value(FromDate) over(order by FromDate), ToDate) + 1 as varchar(10)) 
from #Temp`

Comment: This works. Still cannot up-vote your answer as I have less than 15 reptation

Comment: `min()` seems so much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if you want exactly the same output

```
Select 
      * ,
     case 
      when (FromDate != ToDate) 
       then 
        'Day '+ DATEPART(Day,FromDate) + '-' + DATEPART(Day,ToDate)
       else
      'Day '+ DATEPART(Day,FromDate)
      END AS Display
    From #Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the previous row's value, you want the earliest fromdate, and then you can compare it to every row.

```
select id, min (fromdate) over (order by fromdate asc) as earliest_date,fromDate,todate,
datediff(day,min (fromdate) over (order by fromdate asc),fromdate)+1,
datediff(day,min (fromdate) over (order by fromdate asc),todate)+1
from
#temp
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=084faa42d6be73fd0a1f87a9bc4322db)